# My iPad's MAC address seems to have changed with the iPadOS 14 update. Is this normal?

Tags: ios, software-update, privacy, watchos, ipados

I was looking at my Ubiquiti UniFi controller webpage and noticed that my iPad Pro 10.5 was seen as a new device. I went to the Insights tab and saw that it has two entries, with two different MAC addresses.

Why has the MAC address changed? Does this sort of thing happen usually and I have only noticed it this time because of the UniFi controller webpage?

Comment: I’ll have to look on mine - interesting if this is systematic.

Comment: @bmike It looks like it's a new setting for Private MAC address https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211227

Comment: Very nice! Another bonus for resetting network settings to clear cruft...

Comment: Hmm… if this is on by default, that's at least a heads up that I'll either have to go through my router settings & re-do the fixed address allocations, or switch it off at home… trying to decide which might be best.

Comment: @Tetsujin Switching it off at home seems reasonable, you probably don't have a reason to hide the MAC address of your own device from yourself :-)

Comment: @nohillside - LOL, yeah - that's true ;-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortly after posting the question, I found out that there is a new feature in iOS/iPadOS/WatchOS that changes the MAC address to an individual private one for every wifi network. I think I will be turning it off for my own wifi networks.

It seems to be turned on by default.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211227